# How can I setup in Elastix 1.5 the "Monitor Trunk Failures" feature?

Tags: email, alert, voip, asterisk, trunk

[image]

I dont know where to save the script or how to link it in this field. I found this script on a different website, and I feel that it would work fine for what I need it to do, just alert me via email when the truck is down.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "You're screwed, the trunk you bought is down"|mail -s "You have a problem" email@domain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the AGI script into the directory

/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin

and make sure it's executable with $chmod +x

Then put the full name to the script into the box, and enable it with the checkbox.